# Acquiring UK permanent residence through a parent for EU citizen

Tags: united-kingdom, eu-citizens

I'm an EU citizen resident in the UK for more than 10 years and am in the process of applying for a permanent residence document to apply for British citizenship. This question relates to my 17 year old son, also an EU citizen who has been exercising his EU Treaty Rights since 2016.

Per the GOV UK website:

> **If your parent is eligible for settled status**
>
> You’ll be eligible for settled status once your parent has settled
>   status, even if:
>
> - you’ve lived in the UK for less than 5 years
> - you arrive in the UK after 31 December 2020

Even through he will not be eligible for settled status on his own as he doesn't meet the residence criteria, it's quite clear that he will automatically be eligible for settled status after mine is granted.

However, I'm not quite sure what happens if I apply and be granted British citizenship before he applies and is granted his settled status. Should I therefore not apply before that?

Also, does the procedure relating to settled status after UK's exit from the EU depend on any kind of deal or no deal with the EU? What I'm getting at is if what is outlined on the GOV UK page likely to change? The following quote makes it as if it was all rock solid as only that one part, completely irrelevant to me, is subject to any kind of approval.

> How long you can live outside the UK is still subject to approval by Parliament.

It is quite important for us to know as it will help him decide whether to apply to study abroad or not.

Lastly, my timeline for applying for British citizenship was to wait at least 6 years - 5 years to be eligible to apply for British citizenship and another year to hold the document for at least a year. However, as my son is going to receive settled status in his 3rd year of residence. Therefore, are we correct in understanding that he will be able to apply for citizenship in June 2021, after 5 years of residence?

Answer (score 1):

> However, I'm not quite sure what happens if I apply and am granted British citizenship before he applies and is granted his settled status.

This is irrelevant. Everything depends on previous dates of permanent residence, not current citizenship.

> Also, does the procedure relating to settled status after UK's exit from the EU depend on any kind of deal or no deal with the EU?

Unknown for certain at this point. There have been proposals. There is strong evidence and likelihood that there will be some sort of transition period/arrangements, but nothing is certain.

> Lastly, my timeline for applying for British citizenship was to wait at least 6 years - 5 years to be eligible to apply for British citizenship and another year to hold the document for at least a year.

Your date of acquiring permanent residence is not necessarily the date you get the PR document. It may be (very probably, I'd even say) that you have already met the criteria of living in the UK one full year after acquiring permanent residency. In which case, as soon as you have the PR document in hand, along with all of the other required documents, you can apply immediately. This is something to consider as this might change your assumed dates a bit.

Comment: For example, you might submit as evidence five P60 forms proving you were employed in the UK from April 2013 to April 2018. If you apply now, get the PR document say Feb 2019, then it will say that you have PR since April 2018, and you can apply for citizenship in April 2019.